# jquery, get id of dropdownlist when button is clicked

Tags: jquery

My dom looks like:

```
<td>

<select id=s1 class=c1>...</select>
<select id=s2 class=c1>...</select>
<select id=s3 class=c1>...</select>
<input type=button id=btn value=click/>
</td>
```

Now when the page loads, I do a `$(".c1").hide();` and then based on other logic, make one of them visible.

Now when the button is clicked, I want the ID of the drop down list that is currently visible.

How can I do this?

Comment: 851 questions.....51% accept....come on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("select.c1:visible").attr("id")
```

Should return you the ID of the first visible select element.

Also please quote your attribute values.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#btn').click( function(){

    $('select.c1:visible').get(0).id

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select:visible").attr("id")
```

BTW, you should be aware that IDs are not the only way to find and handle elements in JavaScript. I mean that `$("select:visible")` already contains the element itself!